# boost::replace_all whole word issue

Tags: regex, boost

my regex doesn't works. Why?

```
boost::regex re("anonuuid|anon_id", boost::regex::icase);
target_string = "anonuuid final.device_anonuuid anon_id";
boost::replace_all(target_string, "anonuuid", "device_anonuuid");
```

The idea is to find and replace the WHOLE word anonuuid OR anon_id. I've used the word boundary tag \b but even with it, it's not working. Below is the result of my code.

```
device_anonuuid final.device_device_anonuuid anon_id"
```

But i wish to get this

```
device_anonuuid final.device_anonuuid device_anonuuid
```

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What regex were you using?

Comment: This one `boost::regex re("anonuuid|anon_id", boost::regex::icase)`

Comment: I don't see a word boundary matcher in there.

Comment: I've tried this `boost::regex re("\banonuuid\b|\banon_id\b", boost::regex::icase);` but the result is this `device_anonuuid final.device_device_anonuuid anon_id`

Comment: Your code doesn't actually use `re`. You probably want `boost::regex_replace`.

Comment: this `target_string = boost::regex_replace(target_string, re, "device_anonuuid");` is not work too :( The result string stay unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `regex_replace_all`, see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e64bf46b3c7ecac)**.

Also note:

- you need to escape `\b` (e.g. `"\\b"`)
- you need to pass an lvalue as format
- there's also `regex_replace_all_copy` that returns a *new string* instead of modifying the input string

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string_regex.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::regex re("\\b(anonuuid|anon_id)\\b", boost::regex::icase);
    std::string target_string = "anonuuid final.device_anonuuid anon_id";
    std::string format = "QQQQ";
    boost::replace_all_regex(target_string, re, format, boost::match_flag_type::match_default);

    std::cout << target_string;
}
```

Comment: Typos in text (not in code) - `regex_replace_all` (should be `replace_all_regex`) and `regex_replace_all_copy` (should be `replace_all_regex_copy`). Why not just use `regex_replace` (without including `boost::algorithm`)? Also, I don't believe `format` has to be an lvalue.

Comment: Thanks, ti works. But why should I escape 'b' twice?

Comment: @Measis Because `\b` is already an escape in the C and C++ languages http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape